# How To Pass e.parameter to Html Page in Google App Script Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script take a user from a URL Parameter and number of emails as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpq9J.png)

However "UserName" is being displayed with Quotes is it possible to stop this  code is shown below,

extracts from index.html

```
<script>
      function onSuccess2(jUserName) 
         {
            var div = document.getElementById('output2');
            div.innerHTML = 'You User Name Is ' + jUserName
          }

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2)
              .getUserName();
</script>
```

```
<body>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="output2"></div>
</body>
```

code.gs

```
const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  UserName=JSON.stringify(e.parameter['UserName']);
  userProperties.setProperty('UserName', UserName);
  Logger.log("UserName= "+UserName);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

 function getUnreadEmails() {
  return GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
}



function getUserName() {
  Logger.log("Getting User Name");
  return userProperties.getProperty("UserName");
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result from your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `getUnreadEmails()` is not used.
- In your situation, I thought that when an HTML template is used, the script might be simple. And also, when `google.script.run` is used, it is run after the HTML was loaded. By this, when an HTML template is used, this cost might be able to be reduced.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### HTML side: `Index.html`

```html
<body>
  <div id="output">Count: <?= count ?></div>
  <div id="output2">You User Name Is <?= userName ?></div>
</body>
```

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  html.count = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
  html.userName = e.parameter['UserName'];
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

- When this Web Apps is accessed with a URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?UserName=sample`, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    Count: 123
    You User Name Is sample
  ```

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)